# Writing a simple parser

Tags: c++, parsing, dsl

I need to write a simple parser to a sort of Domain Specific Language.
It needs to have basic arithmatics with proper operators evaluation order and a syntax to call functions of the underlying environment which can be overloaded.
What is the simplest way to write such a parser? Is there something I can adapt or use out of the box? I'm writing in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Boost Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/doc/quick_start.html).

Answer (score 3):

See MetaII parser technology.  This tutorial walks you through everything:

http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) parse some data. It worked pretty well for me.